# How to convert multiple rows into different columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have raw data like below

```
UserId Email Name Age
101    abc   xyz  30
101    def   xyz  30
101    ghi   xyz  30
```

and looking for output like below

```
UserId Email1 Email2 Email3 Name Age
101    abc    def    ghi    xyz  30
```

Raw data could have single or multiple emails, so I am trying to get a generic way of doing it. Right now I am struggling to get it done. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Presuming that another user will have 2 emails and another 5 - it will be a little tricky.  Perhaps a stored procedure that creates a temp table with enough fields to store the most emails a user has.

Comment: Do you know the maximum e-mails number any user could have upfront (at design)?

Comment: perhaps, i was trying a similar approach

Comment: Since you tagged your question with  `PL/SQL` I added `Oracle` tag as well.

Comment: Check out the list of "related" answer at the right edge.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [listagg function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030). It won't give you real columns, but you could make it look like it did by formatting the output accordingly.